# Insert Symbol in Text box VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code to insert a textbox into a word document:

```
Sub mark()
    Dim Box As Shape
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=20, Top:=20, Width:=20, Height:=20)
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "tick"
End Sub
```

The text inside the texbox needs to be:

```
Selection.InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings", CharacterNumber:=-3844, Unicode :=True
```

Comment: I Figured it out: Box.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSymbol 252, "Wingdings", True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've found an answer, but there's a more optimal way to use the method you found. Since it's not possible to format code nicely in Comments I'm writing it up in the Answer space for you (and others who might have the same question). Also, the site prefers the useful information to be in an "Answer" since Comments tend to be over-looked or deleted...

In order to insert content from the Insert Symbol dialog box, use the `InsertSymbol` method, which applies to either the `Range` or the  Selection`object.

Using the `Range`object is always the preferred approach. In order to get a Range object for the text box content, adjust your code something like this:

```
Sub mark()
  Dim Box as Word.Shape
  Dim rngBox as Word.Range
  Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextBox( _
            Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
            Left:=20, Top:=20, Width:=20, Height:=20,  _
  Set rngBox = Box.TextFrame.TextRange
  rngBox.Text = "tick"
  rngBox.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'focus at end of Range
  rngBox.InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings", CharacterNumber:=-3844, Unicode:=True
End Sub
```

The `Collapse` method allows you to continue adding text (optionally with formatting) for as long as you require...